# What do I do if I can't unlock shouts?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I didn't complete the quest 'Talk to Alvor in Riverwood' because I accidentally stole from the bartender and now I can't turn in my quest.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you pay you bounty in Riverwood?

Comment: idk the good thing is that riverwood doesn't hate me anymore but the bad thing is i cant complete the quest even if i talk to him

Comment: i think i already have and i think everyone hates me because i have really high bounty (around 15,000) and when they attacked me i attacked them and killed about 3 guards and 4 people in solitude, riften, and dawnstar and now they hate me because i killed  guards and stuff

Comment: now i store ALL my gold in my base/camp which is knifepoint ridge

Comment: UPDATE now river wood hates me and i got so ticked off i killed everyone except the two kids and delfine or whatever her name is (i know i couldnt kill her because she helps me defeat dragons and stuff but i dont get why i cant kill kids)

Answer (score 6):

It seems that there's a bug, have you tried this? http://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/458210-talking-to-alvor-bug/

This guy exhausted every conversation and the arrow still appears over him, the answer was:

> - Talk to him
> - take all his supplies
> - exit trade window (where you take his supplies)
> - DONT touch keyboard/controller, he will start the dialogue by him self
> - let him do dialogue, wait for him to finish
>     --> Questupdate

Also, have you tried to pay the fine? 
Take a look at this, this guy had a similar problem: 
[Alvor keeps trying to kill me, can't advance the story](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39776/alvor-keeps-trying-to-kill-me-cant-advance-the-story). Although his problems were because he went murdering people before talking to Alvor, so that everyone wanted to kill him... but maybe some of the answers can help.

If nothing works, then maybe the game is ruined and you have to start all over again s:

Comment: Hey, @Eirikra, could you summarize what you found in those links?  We don't want to suffer from link rot, and when possible, want to have as much information on site as possible.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm sorry I'm new here hehe. I will do it right now :)

Comment: i will try the bug thx

Answer (score -1):

A lot of people restart the game, even at level 50 or so. So you need to restart to the last save that you had before you completed that quest.

If you delete the save, well... you're gonna have to restart from scratch.

Sorry if this happened to you.