# Skyrim (PC) How do you make citizens un hostile?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I'm doing a Dawnguard quest with Serana and it is very challenging (for me at  least). I got very very frustrated and tried to kill her, but she is "important" so it didnt work. I used the command `Tdetect` so she wouldn't try to kill me, but every time I talk to her she's always like "you never should have come here" and trys to kill me. I can't leave the quest and the last time I saved I had imperial armor, so I cant start a new game because now I have the Nightingale gear.

Is there any type of spell or console command to fix it? I would really apprieciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

## Check your Bounties

Goto your Journal menu and change to the Stats menu.
Inside, goto the "Crime" tab and check to make sure you don't have any current bounties.
If you do, goto the respective hold, and try to get the guards to sheath and offer a Jail Sentence.

Weather you want to pay a bounty (if possible) or goto Jail is up to you. It will un-hostile all guards and people in that hold/city.

## Wait

Some people claim that leaving people for a day or two (In game) will reset your status and thus making the NPC friendly again. **Note: This may not *actually* work...**

## Other

You can try console commands which **MAY** bug up your game so be careful!

Also, you may want to try the below solution from [**this**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39776/alvor-keeps-trying-to-kill-me-cant-advance-the-story) Arqade question.

> Open console, then click on npc, and enter:
>
> <kbd>stopcombat</kbd>

Comment: Doesn't calm spell make an npc stop combat?

Comment: @Jim I think that was an edit, I can't see it, but if you can, yes, it only calms them.

Comment: i'm banned from editing since I didn't make good edits i'll make better edits and then edit this one.

Comment: @Jim Ah, so you did it. Good luck, but don't add the Calm spell. It only stops the combat, not the "hate" for future returns.

Answer (score -1):

Open Console, target npc, use command `setav aggression 0`

Comment: Could use a little bit more explanations.